# Coroutines with LiveData

Tags: android-room, coroutine, android-jetpack

Get compilation error when try to run the below code :

The code success fully run if i changed the return type to List, but i wanted to return the live data object from the suspended function.

```
@Dao
interface TodoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from Todo where category_name = :category_name")
    suspend fun getAllTodo(category_name : String) :LiveData<List<Todo>>
}
```

```
Compiler throws error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (LiveData<List<Todo>>).
public abstract java.lang.Object getAllTodo(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

```
    def room_version = '2.1.0-beta01'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    //View model
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-beta01'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0-beta01"

    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.1"
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

remove suspend cuz it is already suspend function when you said return LiveData
Your code looks like:

```
suspend suspend fun getAllTodo(category_name : String) :LiveData<List<Todo>>
```

here is correct one:

```
 fun getAllTodo(category_name : String) :LiveData<List<Todo>>
```

but if you will use repository, then there you need write suspend, but not in DAO, don't forget use, for example in ViewModel, coroutines:

```
 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
...dao.getAllTodo(category_nam)...
}
```